SQL to JSON Need Bracket for Array that can have multiple rows
I'm trying to take a SQL query and turn it into JSON for an API call.  I have two groupings that need to contain an opening and closing bracket [] because they can contain multiple rows.  Those are shown here as  [fulfillments] & [shipments].  I have it formatted correctly below
{
    "customer_order": {
        "order_number": "12394334"
    },
    "fulfillments": [
        {
            "fulfillment_id": "12394334"
        }
    ],
    "destination": {
        "contact": {
            "person_name": "Johnny Pops",
            "phone_number": 777777777,
            "email_address": "JohnnyPops@gmaill.com"
        },
        "address": {
            "street_line1": "1708 Johnny Pops DRIVE",
            "city": "AUSTIN",
            "postal_code": 78745,
            "state_or_province_code": "TX",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    },
    "shipments": [
        {
            "shipment_id": "BLDT11121",
            "fulfillment_id": "BLDT11121",
            "tracking_number": "BLDT11121",
            "carrier_scac": "SSSS"
        }
   ]
}

Using a FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER works but I can't get those brackets in the proper place:
SELECT 
    [Order Number] AS [customer_order.order_number], [Order Number] AS [fulfillments.fulfillment_id]
    ,[Last Name] AS [destination.contact.person_name], [Home Phone] AS [destination.contact.phone_number], email AS [destination.contact.email_address]
    ,[Address] AS [destination.address.street_line1], [city] AS [destination.address.city], zip AS [destination.address.postal_code]
    ,[State] AS [destination.address.state_or_province_code], 'US' AS [destination.address.country_code]
    ,[Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.shipment_id], [Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.fulfillment_id], [Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.tracking_number]
    ,'SEKW' AS [shipments.carrier_scac]
FROM vw__orders
WHERE [Order Number] = '12394334'

If I do a bunch of REPLACE() I can get it to work but I was curious if there was syntax I'm missing?
REPLACE(SQL, '"fulfillments":{"', '"fulfillments":[{"')


I don't see how you expect to have multiple shipments or multiple fulfillments with that query. How would you ever end up with an array with more than one element?

Please tag the RDBMS you use

Also sample data please

Thanks everyone.  Charlieface had the solution I needed.  My data will never have multiples in the data set but that is how their API is expecting it.  I'm using Azure SQL

You can just use nested FOR JSON PATH clauses without a FROM.
SELECT 
    [Order Number] AS [customer_order.order_number],
    (
        SELECT
            [Order Number] AS fulfillment_id
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS fulfillments,
    [Last Name] AS [destination.contact.person_name],
    [Home Phone] AS [destination.contact.phone_number],
    email AS [destination.contact.email_address],
    Address AS [destination.address.street_line1],
    city AS [destination.address.city],
    zip AS [destination.address.postal_code],
    State AS [destination.address.state_or_province_code],
    'US' AS [destination.address.country_code],
    (
        SELECT
            [Order Idwaybill] AS shipment_id,
            [Order Idwaybill] AS fulfillment_id,
            [Order Idwaybill] AS tracking_number
            'SEKW' AS carrier_scac
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS shipments
FROM vw__orders
WHERE [Order Number] = '12394334';

Note however, that this won't put multiple rows into the object unless you use a FROM. There may be some other method using GROUP BY and STRING_AGG, but your schema design is not clear, and appears to be denormalized.

You can use 'FOR JSON AUTO' after your select statement
SELECT 
[Order Number] AS [customer_order.order_number], [Order Number] AS [fulfillments.fulfillment_id]
,[Last Name] AS [destination.contact.person_name], [Home Phone] AS [destination.contact.phone_number], email AS [destination.contact.email_address]
,[Address] AS [destination.address.street_line1], [city] AS [destination.address.city], zip AS [destination.address.postal_code]
,[State] AS [destination.address.state_or_province_code], 'US' AS [destination.address.country_code]
,[Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.shipment_id], [Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.fulfillment_id], [Order Idwaybill] AS [shipments.tracking_number]
,'SEKW' AS [shipments.carrier_scac] 
FROM vw__orders FOR JSON AUTO 
WHERE [Order Number] = '12394334' 

